# Discord bot joining VC

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to get my bot to join a VC but it doesnt work.

Here is what I got

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.voice_channel
    await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

I dont know if this is useful but this is the error message I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 74, in join
    channel = ctx.author.voice.voice_channel
AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation for the [`discord.VoiceState` object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState), you'll find that the attribute is `channel`, not `voice_channel`. Hence:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

or just

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    await client.join_voice_channel(ctx.author.voice.channel)
```